# Two issues while trying to update wordpress user meta

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, post, switch-statement

I have a form that is submitting data to a php script. Here is some of the code in the script.

```
foreach ($newuser_values as $key => $value) {
        echo $key;
        echo $value;
            switch ($key) {
                case "show_name":
                    echo "1";
                    switch ($value) {                       
                        case "first":
                        $update_val = $current_user->user_firstname;
                        break;
                        case "first_initial":
                        echo "HI";
                        $update_val = $current_user->user_firstname . " " . substr($current_user->user_lastname,0,0) . ".";
                        break;
                        case "first_last":
                        $update_val = $current_user->user_firstname . " " . $current_user->user_lastname;
                        break;
                        default:
                        echo "HELLO";
                        $update_val = $user_identity;
                    }
                    echo $update_val;
                    update_user_meta($user_ID, $show_name, $update_val);
                    echo get_user_meta($user_ID, $show_name);
                    ...
             }
        }
```

$newuser_values is an array of form info. I get it like this:

```
$newuser_values = $_POST['edit-profile'];
```

I have two issues here. They can both be seen from the beginning of the script output (from echo statements). The script output is:

show_namefirst_intital1HELLOtestuser1Array

Problem 1: As you can see, the script prints a 1 which means that it is entering the case titled "show_name" of the switch on $key. However, it does not enter the case entitled "first_intial" of the switch on $value. Why is this?

Problem 2: Anyway the script enters the default case of the switch on $value and prints HELLO. Then, it prints the $update_val which is the testuser1. However, that value is not getting assigned to the user_meta because it is printing "Array". Why is this?

Thanks in advance. I apologize if these questions are simplistic. I am pretty new to wordpress and web development.

Comment: $user_identity seems to be an array, but your code does not show where it is declared.

Comment: No, because I have the echo $update_val statement. That is resulting in testuser1 which is just a string

Comment: get_user_meta($user_ID, $show_name) will return an array unless you pass in a third parameter (true).  Try print_r(get_user_meta($user_ID, $show_name)); instead of echo, and see what the Array values are.  Or try print_r(get_user_meta($user_ID, $show_name, true)); to check for a single returned value.

Comment: print_r (get_user_meta($user_ID, $show_name, true)) provided: Array ( [first_name] => Array ( [0] => hank ) [last_name] => Array ( [0] => collins ) [nickname] => Array ( [0] => testuser3 ) [description] => Array ( [0] => ) [rich_editing] => Array ( [0] => true ) [comment_shortcuts] => Array ( [0] => false ) [admin_color] => Array ( [0] => fresh ) [use_ssl] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [show_admin_bar_front] => Array ( [0] => true ) [wp_capabilities] => Array ( [0] => a:1:{s:6:"author";b:1;} )...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the cause of your first issue is a typo. You wrote that your script prints

show_namefirst_intital1HELLOtestuser1Array

so it seems there is a typo as the value of $value is "**first_intital**" instead of "**first_initial**" as you check in your switch case.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured out the second issue.

Instead of this:

```
update_user_meta($user_ID, $show_name, $update_val);
```

It should be this:

```
update_user_meta($user_ID, "show_name", $update_val);
```